# SQL Server how to make a good structured database with different tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to create an application that loads data from a database by selecting  month and year: https://gyazo.com/8a08f56231900945d20dc3801993834a

The thing is that I don't know how the structure of the database.

For example: I need to know the salary of an employee of the year January 2010 and February 2015. Do I need to create tables `tbl2010January` and `tbl2015February`? That seems to be ultra noob to create 12 different tables for each year.

The problem that I also might have is how do I make a relation of an employee in every table?

For example: does an Employee1 need to have a relation with every table from `tbl2010January` till `tbl2016December`?

Can someone please help me out with this problem? I'm not so experienced with programming but am eager to learn!

Comment: Also excuse my English, I hope my question is understandable :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need is a singular salary table with either (Employee Id, Year, Month) OR (Employee Id, Date)

You'll need to create some indexes on Employee ID and the date or year/month.

This way you can create queries to either sum the entire year and get individual months without the need for separate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Salary
(
    fkEmployeeId int,
    Salary decimal,
    SalaryYear int,
    SalaryMonth int
);

CREATE INDEX IX_Salary_Employee_Date ON Salary(fkEmployeeId, SalaryYear, SalaryMonth)

DECLARE @Year int = 2016
DECLARE @Month int = 1

SELECT *
FROM Salary s
INNER JOIN MyEmployeeTable e on e.pkEmployeeId = s.fkEmployeeId
WHERE SalaryYear = @Year and SalaryMonth = @Month
```

Comment: would you be so kind to post an example or provide me with some links?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include code for MSSQL, if you can tell me what DB engine your using then I can provide you with links. 

No need to down vote straight away.

Comment: Oh, sorry, oh well.

Comment: I did found a way oo how to make the database, now the challenge for me will be how do I program all of this stuff since I'm not so experienced with programming :P

Comment: [MsSql Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx)
[Guide to accessing sql through c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

These should help if your using .net